# Multiple problems converting a Map to a List in DataTable builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some key/value data in a Map I wish to display in a flutter DataTable(), but I'm having a problem getting the syntax of the builder correct.

The row argument needs to be List`<DataRow`>

So far I've tried:

```
row: List<DataRow>.of(searchResultItem.detailsDataMap.forEach((k, v) =>
  DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(k)), DataCell(Text(v))])))
```

which gives: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

And, trying to cast it:

```
row: List<DataRow>.of(searchResultItem.detailsDataMap.(forEach((k, v) =>
  DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(k)), DataCell(Text(v))])) as DataRow))
```

which gives: The getter '(' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

And finally mapping it:

```
row: List<DataRow>.of(searchResultItem.detailsDataMap.map<DataRow>((String key, dynamic value) =>
  DataRow(null)))
```

which gives: The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'.

What might be a way of going this that works?

Answer (score 1):

Seems easier to map over the entries.  The following works:

```
          rows: searchResultItem.detailsDataMap.entries
            .map(
              (entry) => DataRow(
                cells: [
                  DataCell(Text(entry.key.toString())),
                  DataCell(Text(entry.value.toString()))
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
```